# STL Sort on nested Classes

Tags: c++, stl, graph, operator-overloading

I have a graph class that has a vector of nodes. In each node, there is a vertex and a STL list of edges. Essentially it's an adjacency list.

For my assignment, I am trying to display the vertices with the most edges. I figured I would sort the graph's vector of nodes by edge size and print the top N vertices.

So I am trying to figure out STL sort, but I'm having difficulties.

I have

```
 std::sort(path.begin(), path.end());
```

Where path is the vector of nodes (node = vertex value and list of edges)

In my node class, I have

```
bool operator<(const Node<T>& rhs){
    return size < rhs.size; //size is how many edges the vertex has
}
```

But it's giving me errors. How can I construct the `operator<` function in my node class to work with STL sort?

Here are the errors:

```
$ make
g++ -c -g -std=c++0x graphBuilder.cpp
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i486-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/algorithm:63:0,
             from graph.h:6,
             from graphBuilder.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_algo.h: In function '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<Node<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<Node<std::basic_string<char> > > > >, _Tp = Node<std::basic_string<char> >]':
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2249:70:   instantiated from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<Node<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<Node<std::basic_string<char> > > > >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2280:54:   instantiated from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<Node<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<Node<std::basic_string<char> > > > >, _Size = int]'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_algo.h:5212:4:   instantiated from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node<std::basic_string<char> >*, std::vector<Node<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<Node<std::basic_string<char> > > > >]'
graph.h:32:13:   instantiated from 'void Graph<T>::topN(int) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]'
graphBuilder.cpp:10:17:   instantiated from here /usr/lib/gcc/i486-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2211:4: error: passing 'const Node<std::basic_string<char> >' as 'this' argument of 'bool Node<T>::operator<(const Node<T>&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]' discards qualifiers
make: *** [graphBuilder.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What errors? That would help to diagnose.

Comment: Its considered a good practice to include error messages in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your member function needs to be `const`-qualified:

```
bool operator<(const Node<T>& rhs) const{
```

### EDIT

Per request, here is a bit more how I knew that you needed to make the member function `const`.

Divining the hidden meanings in stdlib-related compiler errors is something of an art, and something that you get better at with practice.  Stdlib-related errors will often emit a whole series of compiler errors.  Usually the most useful of these errors is the last one, because that one is generated from the context of the code you actually wrote, rather than coming from the bowels of the library code.

In this case, the last compiler error was:

> graphBuilder.cpp:10:17:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i486-slackware-linux/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_algo.h:2211:4:
>   error: **passing 'const Node** >' **as 'this'**
>   argument of 'bool Node::operator<(const Node&) [with T =
>   std::basic_string]' **discards qualifiers**

I've highlighted the illuminating bits.  This tells me that in OP's actual code, because of how the code is constructed (maybe the `sort` call is itself in a `const` member function?  who knows...) the `this` pointer must be `const`, but as we can see from the posted declaration of `operator<`, the method is not `const`.  The "qualifiers" referred to in the compiler errors are what the Standard calls "cv-qualifiers".  "cv" stands for "const/volatile."

When the compiler says "Passing `const X` as `this` to `Node::operator<` discards qualifiers" what it's really trying to say is:

"You said `X` was const but then you tried to call a non-const member function through `const X`.  In order for me to make this call, I would have to *discard* the const qualifier on `X`.  I'm not allowed to do that, so you have to fix your code."

The qualifiers being "discarded" here are the qualifiers on the method itself.  In other words, `operator<` must be a const member function, but it's not.

Comment: I did see that error and fixed it, but it was still erroring out (see above) but I added the const to the end of the function, and it works now :D thanks

Comment: Can you please add more detail why does making operator `<` const , solves the issue? thanks

Comment: @Anibus:  Done.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool operator<(const Node<T>& rhs) const {
    return size() < rhs.size();
}
```

Making the operator `const` as it should be may help with not angering the compiler.

Note: The problem arises because `this` is always `const` so the compiler expects you to promise not to change it which you specify by making the method using `this` to have the `const` qualifier.

Alternately you could make a non-member comparison for use with sort like so:

```
<template typename T>
struct CompareNodes {
bool operator()(const Node<T>& lhs, const Node<T>& rhs) const
{
     return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
}
};

std::sort(path.cbegin(), path.cend(), CompareNodes<T>());
```